# Evaluating limit of integral

Tags: integration

So i have this integral : $$ \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} dy = -\frac{1}{x} \Big[ e^{-xy} \Big]_0^\infty$$
The integration part is fine, but I'm not sure what i get with the limits, can someone explain this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the limits as $y$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$.  This is simply

$$
\left . - \frac{1}{x} e^{-xy} \right |_0^\infty \;\; =\;\; 0 - -\frac{1}{x} \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

To be explicit: In this case $-\frac{1}{x} \Big[ e^{-xy} \Big]_{y:=0}^{y:=\infty}$ means $-\frac{1}{x} \Big[ e^{-xy} \Big]_{y\,:=\,0}^{y\,:=\,\infty}$.

It does **not** mean $-\frac{1}{x} \Big[ e^{-xy} \Big]_{x\,:=\,0}^{x\,:=\,\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a limit is how many integrals of this form can be evaluated. Let $c$ be a real number and let $I = \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} dy.$ Then,

$$I = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_0^c e^{-xy} dy = \lim_{c \to \infty} \left[ -\frac{1}{x}e^{-xy}\right]_0^c = 0 -\left(-\frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{1}{x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
\int_0^\infty e^{-xy} dy &= \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \int_0^n e^{-xy} dy
\\ &= \dfrac{e^0}{x} - \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \dfrac{e^{-xn}}{x}
\end{align}

And that limit is going to $0$.

$\dfrac{1}{x}$